# awk: cannot open pipe Too many open files

Tags: awk, pipe, getline

I have a file with the following structure

```
#data 28-Sep-2020 16:48:04
#Version 1.1
#start
27-Sep-2020 16:00:22.00      83004     83.004784    uA               1
27-Sep-2020 16:01:22.00      82821     82.821602    uA               1
27-Sep-2020 16:02:22.00      82786     82.786552    uA               1
27-Sep-2020 16:03:22.00      82666     82.666336    uA               1
27-Sep-2020 16:04:22.00      82837     82.837242    uA               1
27-Sep-2020 16:05:22.00      82579     82.579857    uA               1
27-Sep-2020 16:06:22.00      82693     82.693413    uA               1
27-Sep-2020 16:08:22.00      82700     82.700043    uA               1
27-Sep-2020 16:09:22.00      82646     82.646797    uA               1
27-Sep-2020 16:10:22.00      82794     82.794540    uA               1
27-Sep-2020 16:11:22.00      82600     82.600845    uA               1
27-Sep-2020 16:12:22.00      82815     82.815422    uA               1
27-Sep-2020 16:13:22.00      82866     82.866974    uA               1
```

I'm trying to append in a file the first column in a `%Y %-m %-d` date format, the second one in a `%-H %-M` date format and lastly the 4th one as it:

```
2020 9 27     16 0     83.004784
2020 9 27     16 1     82.821602
2020 9 27     16 2     82.786552    
2020 9 27     16 3     82.666336
2020 9 27     16 4     82.837242
2020 9 27     16 5     82.579857
2020 9 27     16 6     82.693413
2020 9 27     16 7     82.700043
2020 9 27     16 8     82.646797
2020 9 27     16 9     82.794540
2020 9 27     16 10    83.004784
2020 9 27     16 11    82.600845
2020 9 27     16 12    82.815422
2020 9 27     16 13    82.866974
```

I thought of using `getline` and the `date` command so this is what I'm doing in an one-liner(I'm just splitting the command here for the sake of clarity) for the first column

```
$awk '{if(NR>=4)parsedate="date --date="$1" +\"%Y %-m %-d\""
                cmd | getline mydate
                close(parsedate);
       if(NR>=4 && NR<=10) print mydate, $4}' inputfile
```

and this is working fine and fast. When I'm trying to do the same for the second column using the following one-liner

```
$awk '{if(NR>=4)parsedate="date --date="$2" +\"%-H %-M\""
                cmd | getline mydate close(parsedate);
       if(NR>=4 && NR<=10) print mydate, $4}' inputfile
```

it's significantly slower (the input file is a large file so I think it's ignoring the `if` statements) and although it prints out what it's supposed to print (i.e. `16 0 83.004784` for the 4th line) it returns the following error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=inputfile FNR=1023) fatal: cannot open pipe `date --date=08:59:22.00 +"%-H %-M"' (Too many open files)
```

What's strange to me is that I'm indeed using the `close()` command so I have no idea why it complains and only on the hour case.

Any ideas are more than welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the error is probably because of not calling `close`. But even after resolving that, if we make one call to system `date` for every log line, and usually logs have many lines, then we have an extremely slow script.

So it is mandatory to use the GNU awk [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) or even better, if requirements allow, like here, to use only [string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html). Usually we just rearrange fields, with the help of `split()` or `match()`, but if there are months to convert to numbers, there is a standard way to do it.

```
awk 'NR>3{ split($1, dat, "-"); split($2, tim, ":")
     m=(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", dat[2])+2)/3
     print dat[3], m, dat[1], tim[1], tim[2], $4 }' file
```

We define the string with all 3-letter months, and for any argument to convert, we get the `index()` where this substring begins, (`Jan` is 1st character, `Feb` 4, `Mar` 7 etc, so `(i+2)/3` will give the month number.

Output:

```
2020 9 27 16 00 83.004784
2020 9 27 16 01 82.821602
2020 9 27 16 02 82.786552
2020 9 27 16 03 82.666336
2020 9 27 16 04 82.837242
2020 9 27 16 05 82.579857
2020 9 27 16 06 82.693413
2020 9 27 16 08 82.700043
2020 9 27 16 09 82.646797
2020 9 27 16 10 82.794540
2020 9 27 16 11 82.600845
2020 9 27 16 12 82.815422
2020 9 27 16 13 82.866974
```

So these are the data, you can use `printf` for any formatting you may want.